# Are there any practical applications of Mott insulators and Superfluids?

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

The potential applications of Bose-Einstein condensated is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2708/), I was wondering whether anyone could produce a similar argument for [Superfluids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluidity) and [Mott insulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_insulator).

EDIT: I fully realise they are different effects, I am just asking about them in the same question because they are both novel states of matter.

**In short:
Is there any piece of equipment, process or phenomenon whose efficiency, stability or accuracy would be greatly enhanced by a superfluid? Or by a Mott insulator?**

Comment: Why should the applications of a superfluids be the same as the application of a Mott insulator ? Beyond, this question is a bit misleading, since you ask of the application of a concept. It's like if you were asking of the potential applications of the concept of liquid ... it's too broad concept to be easy to answer you. In addition note that a Bose-Einstein condensate is just one illustration of the concept of superfluid, so partly your question is answered in the link you provide... As for Mott insulator, do you know example in Nature of them ?

Comment: Well it's very expensive to cool a liquid down to superfluid temepratures, are there any positive outcomes of doing so? Would this ease / increase the efficiency of another process?

No, I don't know of any Mott insulators in nature.

Comment: Well, it's sure it's mot energetically efficient to observe superfluidity, but this the same problem with any experiment I fear. As any new kind of state of matter, superfluidity has interest, more certainly more in terms of fundamental research than in terms of economically efficient applications. I'm pretty sure superfluids have been used in spacecrafts and artificial satellites, since they can be at the heart of really efficient detectors (of rotation) for instance. This is also the historically first discovery of a macroscopic quantum state of matter.

Comment: Some people believe SF can be toy model for the early universe as well. But these examples are in the area of fundamental research still. Please refine your question in order one could answer it. If your question is : will a daily-life object use superfluidity some days soon ? the answer is clearly no. Also, please do not mix the concepts of Mott insulator and superfluidity in your question. So --  one more time -- please refine the concept of what you call "practical", and why you are mixing the concepts of Mott insulator and superfluidity. I do not see any connection between the two concepts

Comment: There's no connection in so far as they are both new states of matter that arise at low temperatures.

Comment: What makes superfluid good detectors for rotation? The fact that they can only have quantised angular momentum?

Comment: My last comment (it seems you are totally unable to click on Edit and neither change nor refine your question, so it's pure time losing for me) : *What makes superfluid good detectors for rotation? The fact that they can only have quantised angular momentum?* Almost: in addition to make something useful, the quantum of rotation should be small enough, and the detection should be easy enough.

Comment: @SuperCiocia It's very expensive to create large works of art, to fund public libraries or municipal firework displays, and to go on nice family skiing holidays: are there any positive outcomes of doing so?

Comment: We build bigger libraries because we have more books, we add computers to access digital files and e-books, thus we invest in technology to enhance the service provided. I.e. by making a library better at what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Now: is there any piece of equipment, process or phenomenon whose efficiency, stability or accuracy would be greatly enhanced by a superfluid? Or by a Mott insulator?

Comment: Of course the comment was in jest. In my opinion superfluidity and other low-temperature quantum phases are of intrinsic interest: their positive outcomes are the enrichment of the human mind and spirit. The practical applications of these systems for studying basic physics are huge (quantum phase transitions, quantum simulation of spin systems, thermalisation, energy transport etc.). However, based on your question I do not think you regard these as applications. The question could be made precise by specifying what qualifications the user needs for the application to count as "practical".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superfluid helium finds an application as a coolant in superconducting systems (http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-45542-6_4#page-1 )